# Чем отличаются "//@value" и "//*[@value]"?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xsl

Объясните пожалуйста, чем отличается

```
    <xsl:for-each select="//@value">
```

от

```
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[@value]">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый выберет атрибуты value, а второй узлы у которых есть атрибут value.